# How does one choose for different source distribution formats?

Tags: python, python-packaging

When I release a package to PyPI, I usually create a sdist and a bdist_wheel. The best practice for built distribtion seems to be clear: Wheel.

But for source distribtions, I see [different formats](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/sourcedist.html). Only zip has the note that it needs an extrernal tool, so which factors should  I consinder when deciding for the format? Simply the resulting file size?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is not true answer here.

The note on the external tool for the zip format indeed says that what is need is **either** an external tool or the zipfile module. And the zipfile module is in the standard distribution since Python 1.6 that I hope is no longer of current use...

If Python fellows have not made a clear choice on one single format, and instead use different defaults depending on the host architecture, I think that I am not allowed to advise you one format for general use.

So I will stick the the *defaults*:

- if you target mainly Windows or Linux use the default for the target system
- if your development teams has chosen one format, use it
- if your development team mainly uses Windows or Linux, use the default for that system

Else, you are on your own, and as far as I am concerned I just use the default for *my* own development system.